# Android: Work Manager: Scheduled worker run vs application on create

Tags: android, android-workmanager

If a worker is scheduled, and I kill the app then when the OS executes the worker, does it create the `Application` (`onCreate` called or not)? If yes what is the sequence of run - does the `onCreate` finish and then worker executes? If the worker execution depends on some initialisation which happens in Application class - can we guarantee that it will be available to the worker?

Any help will be appreciated, could not find any detailed info regarding this.

Comment: You could test this easily by adding a log in the Application onCreate method.

Comment: Yes I did that. What I see is that Application onCreate is called before and it finishes then the worker runs. But I am not sure if it is a consistent behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

After reading `WorkManager` sources my findings got me here:
The `Worker` instance is created and executed in the `WorkManager'`s `SystemJobService`.
Since it's a `Service` it's guaranteed to be executed after the `Application.onCreate` is completed.

Nevertheless I've seen some weird crashes in Firebase Crashlytics when the `Worker` implementation was throwing an exception while trying to access an object that surely must have been available on `Application.onCreate` completion.
It's not happening all the time but it's still present among installs. Maybe some manufacturers are trying to create app components in parallel to improve performance but I don't have any strict evidence for it.